# Problema extensión Remote Container al abrir pod de kubernetes

Tags: visual-studio, visual, kubernetes

Cuando intento realizar el comando attach visual code a un pod de Kubernetes, para abrir el directorio en el code, Me arroja este error:

> Error running command
> remote-containers.attachToK8sContainerFromViewlet: spawn kubectl
> ENOENT. This is likely caused by the extension that contributes
> remote-containers.attachToK8sContainerFromViewlet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo la extensión de kubernetes y remote containers para VCode. Muchas Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error ocurre en general porque no se encuentra el comando kubectl o este da error al ejecutarse, normalmente por no encontrar el kubeconfig.

Hay varias cosas que puedes comprobar:

1. ¿Tienes kubectl instalado correctamente? ¿Lo puedes ejecutar desde el terminal y funciona? Si has hecho una instalación manual (esto pasa en Windows), ¿está su ruta en la variable de entorno `$PATH` (`%Path%` en Windows)?
2. Comprueba que tienes tu kubeconfig en la ruta por defecto: el archivo `~/.kube/config`. A veces pasa que la extensión de Kubernetes de VSCode funciona y lista los recursos de tu cluster, pero es porque se ha especificado el kubeconfig manualmente con la opción "Set Kubeconfig". Sin embargo, esta ruta personalizada no se le pasa a kubectl cuando haces attach.
3. En alguna ocasión me ha pasado en Windows que no se puede encontrar el comando kubectl pese a estar su carpeta en el path y todo. Una manera de descartar si es ese el problema es copiar kubectl a la carpeta de VSCode. En Windows es `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\`
4. Por último, comprueba la configuración de las extensiones Remote Containers y Kubernetes de VSCode. Sobre todo que las rutas especificadas sean correctas, y exista kubectl donde se dice. Mi configuración en Windows es esta:

[image: Configuración de VSCode]

Suerte.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono a la perfección. Llevaba varios días sin dormir, intentando solucionar el problema.